# Can I say Havdalah twice to be Motzi a man?

Tags: halacha

I have a friend who is on the path to becoming more religious. He can't yet read Hebrew. Am I able to day Havdalah for him after I've already said it? Sources are preferable.

Comment: May I ask why you think this is different than any other case of אע"פ שיצא מוציא? Like Kiddush, or Shofar, or Megillah?

Comment: So could I do it for him?

Comment: I'm not saying you could or couldn't. This website isn't for practical questions. You should ask your Rabbi what to do. I'm just confirming that this isn't uniquely a Havdalah question.

Answer (score 2):

The Mishna Berura 296:36 says that if one was already yotzai havdala he cannot say it again just for women, however if there are other men who need to hear it then he may repeat it.

> מן האנשים - ואם האנשים כבר הבדילו לעצמם או שנתכונו לצאת בבהכ"נ לא יבדילו כדי להוציא הנשים אם אין שם זכרים גדולים או קטנים ששומעין ממנו דלהיש חולקין הוא ברכה לבטלה [מ"א וש"א

Another point to consider, brought up by @robev in the comments, is that the person listening must understand what’s happening at the very least. It is better if they understand the translation of what’s being said as well. This is in order to ensure that their actually yotzei havdala with your bracha. Because if they don’t understand and they’re not yotzai, then you wouldn’t be allowed to make havdala for them.

Comment: I believe the Mishnah Berurah in chelek Alef brings an idea you can't be motzi someone if they don't know what you're saying. I forget if that applies everywhere or not, but could be relevant here.

Comment: @robev can it be the Biur Halacha 185:3? He mentions a machlokes about it but concludes it’s definitely better than nothing. However if your repeating the bracha in such a case it might be different and perhaps not allowed?  https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.185.3.1?lang=bi

Comment: In simian 273:4 by kiddush the Halacha is that you can make an extra kiddush if they don’t know how to say it themselves (MB holds you can do it in all cases).  In 484:1 you can make an extra Seder for those who don’t know how to make it themselves. However, perhaps it is referring to a case where they understand the words but just can’t say it themself. If that’s the case, maybe just explain what havdala is and what it means before you make it for him

Comment: Mishnah berura 193:5 says that not understanding lashon hakodesh is not a problem. R’ Chaim Scheinberg in Mahadura Basra on that simian says that they must at least understand what’s happening and not that it’s just some hocus pocus. By davening though there MB 124:2 says they must understand what’s being said. R’ Chaim Kanievski (Ishei Yisroel 198) points out the contradiction